# Used git rebase --skip by mistake during rebase

Tags: git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was rebasing a branch. When conflict arised, I used,

```
git rebase --skip
```

instead of,

```
git rebase --abort
```

(I wanted to restart the rebasing for some reason).

Now when I start the rebasing again, it says the branch is up to date but it does not have all the changes.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can use is the `reflog`. In essence `git reflog` is like `git log` but instead of code commits, it contains all actions one has taken on the git history of the repo.

For example here's the recent reflog from one of my projects:

```
1b229a2 HEAD@{0}: commit: Speed up debug mode a little bit
9976a41 HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): Split LooseTire down to gameplay and presentation
b825442 HEAD@{2}: commit: Split LooseTire down to gameplay and presentation
889e828 HEAD@{3}: commit: Add a couple new interfaces
b82965a HEAD@{4}: commit: Move car to the gameplay folder
55360ae HEAD@{5}: commit: Fix a bug when displaying polygon collision shapes
decd93c HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from 7f06e8fb6bc81566215173b9739b26758a69a82e to master
7f06e8f HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from df922e5c2efcef3e6fc9566747efe9c79eae23b6 to df922e5c2efcef3e6fc9566747efe9c79eae23b6
df922e5 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to df922e5c2efcef3e6fc9566747efe9c79eae23b6
```

As you see there are some checkouts (part of a `git bisect` I was doing) and some commits, even a `commit (amend)`. These are all actions taken on the repo's git history.

Using this as a guide I can `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` for example to get my repo to the state it was before I did `git commit --amend` (2nd line in the reflog).